# Native App for iOS & Android, Displaying Images

Tags: android, ios, mobile

We are developing a new app, on both Android & iOS.
We have different logos we wish to display in different layouts in our app.

I wonder, what's the correct solution for different platforms and different screen,
Resizing on all platforms? let's say i want to create A row with different information, which has image, saved on the server / device,

I wish to display it correctly depends on the screen & device, should i create different images, resize?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be better to create different images, because the sizes of devices are different. To make app look and feel awesome i suggest go with different sizes of images depending on devices